Issues with building Speed Dreams using Emscripten
I'm a bit confused on how to build Speed Dreams, an open source racing game, with Emscripten (to port it to the web). When building with 'emcmake cmake' (emscripten's cmake toolchain), the building process detects emscripten's available dependencies (OpenAL, OpenGL, etc.) but not the unsupported ones that Speed Dreams requires (Zlib, PNG, etc.). The building process throws an error and stops. Okay, makes sense.
Example:
-- Looking for library OpenAL - found
-- Could NOT find OGG (missing: OGG_LIBRARY OGG_INCLUDE_DIR)

I know you have to build the dependencies that aren't supported out of the box, so I downloaded jpeg-9e and built it with emscripten to test it out. I got a .deps folder and a .libs folder which contain O, wasm, PLO, and PO files (and one .a file). What do I do with these? I.e, how do I link this newly built dependency to the build process? Would I have to edit Speed Dream's CMake files? There's quite a few and there are several other dependencies I need to build with emscripten and include :/
update: using 'embuilder build [portName]' gave me the jpeg dependency. This also worked with other dependencies: ZLib, PNG, OGG. However, it did not work with other dependencies that had available ports, like SDL2, Vorbis, etc. Here is the output:
-- Looking for libraries X11 - NOT found
-- Looking for dlopen in dl
-- Looking for dlopen in dl - found
-- Looking for library OpenAL - found
-- Found OGG: C:/Users/prisc/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/libogg.a
-- Looking for library Ogg - found
-- Found VORBIS: C:/Users/prisc/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/libvorbis.a
-- Looking for library Vorbis - found
-- Could NOT find VORBISFILE (missing: VORBISFILE_LIBRARY)
-- Looking for library VorbisFile - NOT found
-- Looking for library ENet - NOT found
-- Looking for library OpenGL - found
-- Looking for library OpenGL/GLU - found
-- Found ZLIB: C:/Users/prisc/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/libz.a (found version "1.2.13")
-- Looking for library Zlib - found
-- Found PNG: C:/Users/prisc/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/libpng.a (found version "1.6.39")
-- Looking for library PNG - found
-- Found JPEG: C:/Users/prisc/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/libjpeg.a (found version "90")
-- Looking for library JPEG - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Could NOT find SDL2 (missing: SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find SDL2 (missing: SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find SDL2 (missing: SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Looking for library SDL2 - NOT found
-- Could NOT find SDL2 (SDL2 is required by SDL2_mixer).
-- Looking for library SDL2_mixer - NOT found
-- Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Looking for library CURL - NOT found
-- Could NOT find osgDB (missing: OSGDB_LIBRARY OSGDB_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find osgViewer (missing: OSGVIEWER_LIBRARY OSGVIEWER_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find osgGA (missing: OSGGA_LIBRARY OSGGA_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find osgUtil (missing: OSGUTIL_LIBRARY OSGUTIL_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find osgFX (missing: OSGFX_LIBRARY OSGFX_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find osgParticle (missing: OSGPARTICLE_LIBRARY OSGPARTICLE_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find osgShadow (missing: OSGSHADOW_LIBRARY OSGSHADOW_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find osgText (missing: OSGTEXT_LIBRARY OSGTEXT_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find osg (missing: OSG_LIBRARY OSG_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find OpenThreads (missing: OPENTHREADS_LIBRARY OPENTHREADS_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSceneGraph (missing: OPENSCENEGRAPH_LIBRARIES
  OPENSCENEGRAPH_INCLUDE_DIR OSGDB_FOUND OSGVIEWER_FOUND OSGGA_FOUND
  OSGUTIL_FOUND OSGFX_FOUND OSGPARTICLE_FOUND OSGSHADOW_FOUND OSGTEXT_FOUND
  OSG_FOUND OPENTHREADS_FOUND) (Required is at least version "3.4.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindOpenSceneGraph.cmake:226 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  cmake/checks.cmake:280 (Find_Package)
  CMakeLists.txt:57 (CHECK_LIBRARIES)

Update: I may have found a way to deal with this. Now my original question still stands: How do I include dependencies that I've built with Emscripten? I still need to build the following: OpenSceneGraph-3.6.5, expat, curl, and enet.
Update: Realized that I just needed to use 'emmake make install' to automatically put necessary files (libraries, the 'include' directories) from the built dependencies into Emscripten's sysroot dir. Also, the previous issue required that I go into the CMake cache file and manually put in the file/dir paths for the ones it claims it can't find, then execute 'emcmake cmake' again.

The CMake find modules won't work with emscripten. You will need to create CMake config files for every piece of software that you build.
